# Flash object stops when reparented

Tags: flash, dom, playback, reparenting

I have to seemlessly pull out the document from under a Flash object. Temporary removal of the object from the DOM stops it playing, which is appreciable, however, moving it around inside the tree, even via an “atomic” operation (calling `appendChild()` on the intended parent without removing the object first) also stops the playback.

Is there any way I can replace the document without the object stopping?

Comment: This behavior is probably browser dependent, is it?

Comment: No, it’s the same across Firefox, Chrome and Opera, at least on my Linux box.